# More efficient way of writing this query?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

I have a stats table (append only) whose active record is the one with the highest `WordsRead` and `MinutesRead` per `UserId`, `BookId`, `UserGroupId` and `Date`.

Now I want to find the total `MinutesRead` and `PagesRead` since a given date.

This query *works*... but it's horribly slow over a large date range:

```
SELECT Minutes = SUM(r.MinutesRead), Pages = SUM(r.PagesRead)
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT r.Date, r.UserId, r.BookId, r.UserGroupId 
        FROM dbo.ReadingStatDaily r 
        WHERE r.Date >= @p0) r0
CROSS APPLY (SELECT TOP 1 r.MinutesRead, r.PagesRead
        FROM dbo.ReadingStatDaily r
        WHERE r0.Date = r.Date AND r0.UserId = r.UserId AND r0.UserGroupId = r.UserGroupId AND r0.BookId = r.BookId
        AND r.Date >= @p0
        ORDER BY r.WordsRead DESC, r.PagesRead DESC) r
```

Execution plan looks like this:

[image: execution plan]

No scans, key lookups or any other low hanging fruit.

Any other ideas how I could get better performance out of this query?

Comment: Please edit your question to include the relevant table's DDL, some sample data as DML and desired result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I optimized it by tweaking an index.  My clue was that 72% of the query cost was in that sort sub-clause.  The index `IX_ReadingStatDaily_User` was indexing the fields `UserId`, `BookId`, `UserGroupId` and `Date`, with `INCLUDE` on `WordsRead` and `PagesRead` (and some other fields).  I moved `WordsRead` and `PagesRead` into the index itself, and suddenly the query is taking a third of the original time.

Comment: What happens if you re-try Felix's deleted answer now? (Which when I read your question was what I would have suggested also)

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever I tried them both after tweaking the index.  Mine is still faster.

Comment: You might not have added the two columns in the optimum order for the rownumber version to avoid a sort. Would need to be `CREATE INDEX IX_ReadingStatDaily_User ON dbo.ReadingStatDaily(Date ASC, UserId ASC, BookId ASC, UserGroupId ASC, WordsRead DESC, PagesRead DESC) include (MinutesRead)`

Answer (score 1):

Another way you could rewrite this is

```
DECLARE @p0 DATE = <what_ever>;

WITH r0
     AS (SELECT Date,
                UserId,
                BookId,
                UserGroupId,
                MAX(RIGHT(CONCAT('000000000', WordsRead), 10) + 
                    RIGHT(CONCAT('000000000', PagesRead), 10) + 
                    RIGHT(CONCAT('000000000', MinutesRead), 10) COLLATE Latin1_General_BIN2) AS highest_words_pages_minutes
         FROM   dbo.ReadingStatDaily
         WHERE  Date >= @p0
         GROUP  BY Date,
                   UserId,
                   BookId,
                   UserGroupId)
SELECT Minutes = SUM(0 + RIGHT(highest_words_pages_minutes, 10)),
       Pages = SUM(0 + SUBSTRING(highest_words_pages_minutes, 11, 10))
FROM   r0
```

Which should give a simpler plan such as

[image]

Assuming your index is something similar to

```
CREATE INDEX IX_ReadingStatDaily_User
  ON dbo.ReadingStatDaily(Date ASC, 
                          UserId ASC, 
                          BookId ASC, 
                          UserGroupId ASC)
  INCLUDE (WordsRead, PagesRead, MinutesRead)
```

Comment: Okeeeey... I'm instinctively recoiling at the conversion of numbers to strings and back.  Won't that be, like, hugely inefficient?.

Comment: @ShaulBehr Potentially more than compensated for by removing that branch of the plan that self joins back onto the table. What do you find when you test?

Answer (score 0):

Would something like this work?

```
select Minutes = SUM(r.MinutesRead), Pages = SUM(r.PagesRead) from (
    SELECT
      Date,
      UserId,
      BookId,
      UserGroupId,
      MinutesRead, 
      PagesRead,
      row_number() over (PARTITION BY Date, r.UserId, r.BookId, r.UserGroupId 
                         ORDER BY r.WordsRead DESC, r.PagesRead DESC) as RN
    FROM 
      dbo.ReadingStatDaily
    WHERE
      Date >= @p0
) X where RN = 1
```